# iTunes windows are white on black after upgrade to 10.7

Tags: macos, itunes, osx-lion

It's easier to show than tell – see this screenshot:

[image]

Here's what I have already looked into:

- **Preferences**: no settings that (seem to) apply here;
- **Universal Access**: in particular, "Assistive Devices" – my first thought
  was that I had inadvertently used a keyboard shortcut that triggered 
  this mode which is in fact an option under Assistive Devices
- **Deleted & Reinstalled iTunes**: including the cache, temporary files in
  `~/Library/Application Support` and `~/Library/iTunes`

I have also surfed the Apple Support forums, and indeed, there are several posts about this, but all of them unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have High Contrast Mode switched on for iTunes. To switch this off, quit iTunes and type the following in Terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.iTunes high-contrast-mode-enable -bool no`

or alternatively:

`defaults delete com.apple.iTunes high-contrast-mode-enable`

Then restart iTunes...